How to understand the singular projective cubic surface $xyz=1$?
Backstory: I encountered this singular cubic surfaces in my study of Severi-Brauer varieties, since, given a cyclic algebra $A$ of degree $9$ over some field $k$ (let's assume it to be perfect), we can easily write down a singular projective cubic surface $X_A$ which is birational to the Severi-Brauer $\operatorname{SB}(A)$ surface corresponding to $A$.
However, I would like to understand the connection between $X_A$ and $\operatorname{SB}(A)$ a little closer. By the general theory of algebraic surfaces, there exists a sequence of blow-ups and blow-downs $X_A \leftarrow \bullet \leftarrow \bullet \leftarrow \cdots \to \bullet \to \bullet \to \operatorname{SB}(A)$. I'd like to know how many times I need to successively blow up and then blow down $\operatorname{SB}(A)$ to get to $X_A$.
For this it is probably enough to forget about the arithmetic structure and pass to the algebraic closure. Since $(X_A)_{\overline{k}}$ is isomorphic to the projective surface $\overline{X}$ defined over $\overline{k}$ given by $xyz=1$ (see below), I would already be much helped by understanding by what sequence of blow-ups and blow-downs the surface $\overline{X}$ is related to $\operatorname{\mathbb P}^2$.

To prove the claim about $X_A$ being $\overline{k}$-isomorphic to $xyz=1$, let $\ell/k$ be a degree $3$ cyclic extension, $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(\ell/k)$ a generator, $a \in k^\times$ a non-zero field element, and $A$ the cyclic algebra associated with the data $(\ell,\sigma,a)$, then we define the surface $X_A$ as the projective surface given by
$$
\operatorname{N}_{\ell/k}(x'\alpha_1+y'\alpha_2+z'\alpha_3)=a,
$$
where $\operatorname{N}_{\ell/k}$ denotes the field norm, and where $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ is a $k$-basis of $\ell$. We see that we can now choose a linear transformation in $x,y,z$ which effects the isomorphism with $xyz=1$.

The surface $X_A$ is toric, the corresponding fan is generated by three vectors:
$$
(1,1),\ (1,-2),\ (-2,1).
$$
It has three singular points of type $A_2$ and is resolved by the blowups of these points, that add 6 more vectors to the fan:
$$
(1,0),\ (1,-1),\ (0,-1),\ (-1,0),\ (-1,1),\ (0,1).
$$
The resulting toric surface $\tilde{X}_A$ can be also obtained by blowing up $\mathbb{P}^2$ with the standard fan generated by
$$
(1,1),\ (0,-1),\ (-1,0)
$$
at two points, then at two points over them, and then at two points over them again.
